# angular2 : open ng2-bootstrap modal from parent component

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I'm trying to open an ng2-bootstrap modal from a parent component. I have created a ModalComponent and I "exportAs: child". My ModalComponent looks like

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'modal',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'modal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['modal.component.css'],
    exportAs: 'child'
})
export class ModalComponent {

    @ViewChild('childModal') public childModal:ModalDirective;

    public show( variant ):void {

        console.log( this.childModal );
        this.childModal.show();
    }

    public hide():void {

        this.childModal.hide();
    }
}
```

and I include the modal in the parent template as

```
<modal #c="child"></modal>
```

... and call it from the parent template as

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="c.show(variant)">open</button>
```

I hit the "show" method inside the ModalComponent correctly but the value of "childModal" is always undefined (Nb: console.log() statement).

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your `modal.component.html` file? And check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/951NyF20qXudDtZo5OAx?p=preview

Comment: Thankyou! I went through your plunker and discovered my mistake was in the HTML as you suspected. I will write the solution below.

Comment: @yurzui just to note that as of today plunker was not working, apparently due to the way *ng2-bootstrap* is loaded from its `<script>` tag. [This fork](https://plnkr.co/edit/ztzPXNTLctmDlLPaDDIt?p=preview) with a different `<script>` tag seems to work. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the  assistance of @yurzui I realised my mistake was in the HTML. I had defined my modal as

```
<div bsModal #smModal="bs-modal"...
```

Nb: "smModal" which needed to be rewritten as

```
<div bsModal #childModal="bs-modal"...
```

... and voila! "childModal" is no longer undefined.

Answer (score 2):

In my view an API for modals that requires you to go through components and query modal instance is far from being optimal. A much better approach is to have a modal as service. This way you can call `open` method on a modal from any place of your code (including services, ex.: login service).

This is exactly why the API for modals is modeled as service in the https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal. By using it you can invoke a modal from *any* place by simply doing `modalService.open(....)`.

BTW, the service-based approach to modals is also present in other Angular2 widget libraries (ex. material design).

In short: re-consider APIs you are using.

Comment: Completely agree. I was looking at using ng2-bootstrap but it confused the hell out of me as it goes against the grain of how most others libraries offer a modal service.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`component.ts` file should be as follows

```
import { Component, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'demo-modal-service-static',
  templateUrl: './service-template.html'
})
export class DemoModalServiceStaticComponent {
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}
 
  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  }
}
```

`html` should be

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template)">Create template modal</button>
 
<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    This is a modal.
  </div>
</ng-template>
```